# Python localhost server/client network code to add/subtract/multiply/divide two numbers?

Tags: python, networking

I've recently been reading "Foundations of Python Network Programming" as I am interested in computer networks and for practice made up some code based off of the first few sample programs I saw in the book.. in this case I "wrote" a TCP server that binds to the localhost and a random port and a client that connects to the localhost. The client gives the server a string consisting of 2 numbers and an operation separated by spaces (i.e. '5 x 4') and the server evaluates this and returns the appropriate value.. my code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket, sys
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 1060

if sys.argv[1] == 'server':
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    while True:
    print 'Now listening at: ', s.getsockname()
    sc, sockname = s.accept()
    print 'We have accepted a connection from', sockname
    print sc.getsockname(), 'is now connected to', sc.getpeername()
    message = sc.recv(1024)
    print 'The client wants to perform the operation: ' + message
    message = message.split()
        if message[1] == '+':
            result = float(message[0]) + float(message[2])
        elif message[1] == '-':
            result = float(message[0]) - float(message[2])
        elif message[1] == '*':
            result = round(float(message[0]) * float(message[2]), 3)
        elif message [1] == '/':
            result = round(float(message[0]) / float(message[2]), 3)
    sc.sendall('The result is ' + str(result))
    sc.close()
    print 'Reply sent as ' + str(result) + '.'
    print

elif len(sys.argv) == 5 and sys.argv[1] == 'client':
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    print 'You are now connected to: ', s.getsockname()
    s.sendall(sys.argv[2] + ' ' + sys.argv[3] + ' ' + sys.argv[4])
    reply = s.recv(1024)
    print 'The return value is', repr(reply)
    s.close()

else:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'usage: addStream.py server or addStream.py client num1 +/-/*// num2'
```

My question is: is this the best way to do this or is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: "Best" is far too ambiguous a term. What are your requirements?

Comment: I guess done in fewer lines (within reason) or runs the most efficient?

Comment: Well, all the socket handling code is about as minimal as you can get away with short of using a python package for servers. For one thing though, your code is single-threaded, so if it takes ten seconds to multiply two numbers, your server will be unresponsive for those ten seconds.

Comment: You haven't got an `else` conditional that will serve the request on malformed input. If the server passes `1 % 3`, the result is an exception since result is not defined.

Comment: For starters, I would decouple the network-related code and the app logic (the math operation).

Comment: Your receive code is buggy.  You'll sometimes try to operate on less than the full message.  Since you have no error handling, any client can also cause your server to exit with an unhandled exception.  You also can only handle one client at a time, so any client can block access to the service for all other clients.  And it would be better to service more than one request per TCP connection, to avoid the constant overhead of re-establishing a new connection to issue a new request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twisted is about the best network engine on offer anywhere. It will handle everything you want in a nice and friendly chunk of code which is both CPU and IO friendly to your machine.
http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/

Comment: Alright I'll be sure to check that out.. on a side note does Twisted support graphs/analyzing/utilizing large-scale networks?

Comment: Probably. It supports everything.

Answer (score -1):

Going forward it is going to be much easier to use some sort of network package instead of just relying on the python standard library.  I think 0MQ would be a good place to start, it has easy to work with and learn python bindings, most of what you are learning already still applies, and it is fast and efficient.

On top of that it doesn't tie you to the python language for all parts of the application, and it doesn't care about the transport method, intraprocess, interprocess, tcp...

http://zeromq.github.com/pyzmq/

Answer (score -1):

I've used this for a few little things: http://docs.python.org/library/asynchat.html

As the docs say, it's more appropriate for i/o bound servers than cpu bound servers.

Comment: Async is just nasty, and you shouldn't really suggest that to beginners.